# PostgreSQL array of data composite update element using where condition

Tags: postgresql

I have a composite type:

```
CREATE TYPE mydata_t AS
(
    user_id integer,
    value character(4)
);
```

Also, I have a table, uses this composite type as an array of `mydata_t`.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl
(
    id serial NOT NULL,
    data_list mydata_t[],
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Here I want to update the `mydata_t` in `data_list`, where `mydata_t.user_id` is **100000**
But I don't know which array element's `user_id` is equal to **100000**
So I have to make a search first to find the element where its `user_id` is equal to 100000 ... that's my problem ... I don't know how to make the query .... in fact, I want to update the `value` of the array element, where it's `user_id` is equal to 100000 (Also where the `id` of `tbl` is for example 1) ... What will be my query?

**Something like this (I know it's wrong !!!)**

```
UPDATE "tbl" SET "data_list"[i]."value"='YYYY'
WHERE "id"=1 AND EXISTS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS i
                         FROM unnest("data_list") "d" WHERE "d"."user_id"=10000 LIMIT 1)
```

For example, this is my `tbl` data:

```
Row1 => id = 1, data = ARRAY[ROW(5,'YYYY'),ROW(6,'YYYY')]

Row2 => id = 2, data = ARRAY[ROW(10,'YYYY'),ROW(11,'YYYY')]
```

Now i want to update `tbl` where `id` is `2` and set the value of one of the `tbl.data` elements to 'XXXX' where the `user_id` of element is equal to `11`

In fact, the final result of `Row2` will be this:

```
Row2 => id = 2, data = ARRAY[ROW(10,'YYYY'),ROW(11,'XXXX')]
```

Comment: Please provide sample test data, as insertable text values or a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14), and the results expected of that data.

Comment: @Belayer hello, updated with some examples...

Comment: Your problems stem from the fact that the data model design is terribly bad. `data_list` should be a table `(id, user_id, value)`, change it asap and forget arrays of composite type forever.

Comment: @klin why do you think that I must forget arrays of composite ? Is there any performance or any other problem about it ? because if i use another table for it, i have to store too many things too ... (in real, tbl has 3 primary keys so i have to store those 3 keys with each data too which will be too much data)

Comment: Because it's an antipattern. Because you have no idea how to perform basic data operations like simple updates. And with this model, there is nothing strange about it. By the way, a table cannot have three primary keys.

Comment: @klin I don't see the problem. In essence it is no different from storing and then manipulating JSON data. It is definitely a departure from a relational data structure but there may be valid reasons to do so

Comment: @Patrick - We don't have to agree. Write an answer, explain all its weaknesses, it will be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the `value` value, you can use the `array_replace()` function to make the change:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET data_list = array_replace(data_list, (11, 'YYYY')::mydata_t, (11, 'XXXX')::mydata_t)
WHERE id = 2
```

If you do not know the `value` value then the situation becomes more complex:

```
UPDATE tbl SET data_list = data_arr
FROM (
    -- UPDATE doesn't allow aggregate functions so aggregate here
    SELECT array_agg(new_data) AS data_arr
    FROM (
        -- For the id value, get the data_list values that are NOT modified
        SELECT (user_id, value)::mydata_t AS new_data
        FROM tbl, unnest(data_list)
        WHERE id = 2 AND user_id != 11

        UNION

        -- Add the values to update
        VALUES ((11, 'XXXX')::mydata_t) 

         ) x 
     ) y
WHERE id = 2
```

You should keep in mind, though, that there is an awful lot of work going on in the background that cannot be optimised. The array of `mydata_t` values has to be examined from start to finish and you cannot use an index on this. Furthermore, updates actually insert a new row in the underlying file on disk and if your array has more than a few entries this will involve substantial work. This gets even more problematic when your arrays are larger than the pagesize of your PostgreSQL server, typically 8kB. All behind the scene so it will work, but at a performance penalty. Even though `array_replace` sounds like changes are made in-place (and they indeed are in memory), the `UPDATE` command will write a completely new tuple to disk. So if you have 4,000 array elements that means that at least 40kB of data will have to be read (8 bytes for the `mydata_t` type on a typical system x 4,000 = 32kB in a [TOAST file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/storage-toast.html), plus the main page of the table, 8kB) and then written to disk after the update. A real performance killer.

As @klin pointed out, this design may be more trouble than it is worth. Should you make `data_list` as table (as I would do), the update query becomes:

```
UPDATE data_list SET value = 'XXXX'
WHERE id = 2 AND user_id = 11
```

This will have MUCH better performance, especially if you add the appropriate indexes. You could then still create a view to publish the data in an aggregated form with a custom type if your business logic so requires.

Comment: +1 for the notes about performance. Though I'm afraid the query is not what the OP meant because it assumes the old `value` is known.

Comment: @klin Thanks for the up-vote and the hint. Answer expanded.

Comment: @Patrick thx but i have a question .... if i know the `value` and i use your first method (`array_replace`) still there is performance problem or not ? for example i have 4000 elements in my array ... using `array_replace` will be OK or still it's bad idea ? because i think using `array_replace` will requires no new array creation ... am i right ?

Comment: @klin You please check my top comment (this post) too ... I would like to hear your answer too ... Thank you.

Comment: See my expanded answer